# Daemon vs worker and when to use what?

Tags: background-process, daemon, process-management, multithreading

(Note that, below, I am frequently using term "*daemon or worker*" just to indicate that I dont know which word to use as I dont know the exact difference between them in the context explained below.)

Consider following scenarios:

1. I need to write a server listening on some port, which accepts a request on that port and fork a new *daemon or worker* for each of incoming requests to handle them.
2. I need to write a server which starts some pre determined number of *daemons or workers*, then listens on some port, and finally it assigns incoming requests on that port to one of currently free *daemons or workers*. This approach pre-creates pre-determined number of *daemons or workers* just to avoid spawning huge numbers of them if I get huge number of requests, which might be the case in first scenario.

I am doing this in linux using python. I have came across two approaches to create *daemon or worker*:

1. By using [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) and setting its [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) to `True`. When I tried this and observed the daemons or workers in the `ps` command output, I realized that *daemons or workers* dont have `PPID=1` (the `initd` process in linux), but their `PPID` is set to the PID (here `28822`) of server. Notice that this approach also leaves those *daemons and workers* in defunct state and they dont get removed from `ps` command output automatically. I have to explicitly kill them.

   ```
   $ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
      PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
    28822  25898  28822  25898  |           \_ python3
    28823  28822  28822  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
    28828  28822  28822  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
    28831  28822  28822  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
   ```
2. However when I do double forking using `os.fork()` <sup>[1](https://franklingu.github.io/programming/2016/03/01/creating-daemon-process-python-example-explanation/),[2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour)</sup> and [handle `singnal.SIGCHLD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24638179/1317018), it does not leave defunct processes and correctly assigns PPIDs of those daemons to 1. For example, following the output of `ps` command:

   ```
   $ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
      PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
    43680  43300  43680  43300  |           \_ python3
    43683      1  43682  43682 python3
    43690      1  43689  43689 python3
    43699      1  43698  43698 python3
   ```

   Those three python processes with PIDs {43683,43690,43699} are *daemons or workers*, then have `PPID=1` and they disappear from command output once they execute fully.

**Doubts**

1. I believe the processes with `PPID=1` as created by double forking are actual unix daemons. Also, notice the [multiprocessing doc says following](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?#multiprocessing.Process.daemon):

   > Additionally, these are not Unix daemons or services, they are normal processes that will be terminated (and not joined) if non-daemonic processes have exited.

   So, I feel the processes created by double forking are real linux daemons while the processes created by multiprocessing library are just workers, even though the library calls them daemons.

   Am I right with this?
2. I want to know which approach will be suitable for above scenarios. I feel scenario 1 should be better implemented with multiprocessing approach, while scenario 2 should be better implemented with double forking approach.

   Am I right with this?

Answer (score 1):

Technically a daemon also needs to call `setsid()` after forking to start a new session, become its leader, and detach from the controlling tty, but yes, you are correct.

You actually want to do both in your two scenarios.  You want to first daemonize, and then the daemon can fork additional workers.

Comment: So you mean the server should call `setsid()`? And each new fork to handle incoming request do not need to call `setsid()`? And this is same for both scenarios?